# Scala Source.fromFile memory consumption

Tags: java, scala, csv, io, heap-memory

All,

I have a CSV file that is only ~120MB (call it `demo.csv`)

The following code results in the Heap blowing up from a normal size of `100MB` to `1.7GB` despite the fact the underlying data being loaded is ONLY `120MB`

What can I do better here?

```
case class Foo(x:String, y: Array[String])
....
val src = Source.fromFile(file)
val lines = src.getLines()
val raw = lines.map(_.split(",")).toArray
src.close()

/**
  * a map from accountId to their benchmark components
  */
val result = raw.groupBy(_.(0)).map {
  case (x, y) => Foo(x,y)
}.toArray
```

I know the `toArray` might be the issue here, however I do need the `groupBy` ... and can't get to it unless I pull everything into memory. What is an alternative?

I understand that the heap might temporarily swell up during the `groupBy` and `toArray` phases. But since the underlying data is only 120MB, how can my heap possibly go up by `>1G` permanently? (in other words, whatever is being retained does not seem to be GC-ed)

Comment: Why aren't you using a List or Seq? Also, it might be worthwhile making your result an iterable to improve performance.

Comment: Replacing array with list does not seem to make a difference. I cannot leave it an iterator because the resulting object from this method must be of the form Seq[Foo] where Foo.y: Array[Array[String]]

Comment: How are you checking on the heap? Java doesn't shrink its heap size, it only grows until it reachs Xmx VM setting. GC only changes the amount of available memory in the heap, not the size of the heap.

Comment: I am using Runtime.getRuntime

Comment: Create a heap dump, install [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)  then check the actual amount of occupied memory and what is occupying it.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: You could use quite a bit less memory, at the possible cost of some runtime performance, by creating your Array[Foo] on the fly. Not in front of a device in which I can code, but if you're not sure where to begin, let me know and I'll write something up. Also, are the two columns really strings, or should they be mapped to more meaningful types - int for the account id, say?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo thank you, if you could provide a skeleton for how to do this that would be great. You also correctly observed that I used `String` for the datatype as a simplification. However, for the most immediate problem I am trying to solve, they are in fact just strings.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'm going to recommend using a dedicated CSV parsing library - manually parsing CSV is much more complex than it looks, there are a lot of edge cases (what if one of your value contains a line break, say?). We'll go with [kantan.csv](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv) because I'm the author, but there are plenty of quality libraries out there.

What we're going to do is:

- open the file as an `Iterator[(String, String)]`.
- fold on that iterator, building a `Map[String, List[String]]` as we go - where keys are account ids and values benchmark data.
- if you're really keen on that `Foo` case class, turn the map into a list of that.

Without further ado:

```
import kantan.csv._     // kantan.csv core types.
import kantan.csv.ops._ // syntax.

case class Foo(id: String, data: List[String])

// Open the CSV file for reading, assuming ; as column separator
// and no header row.
input.asUnsafeCsvReader[(String, String)](';', false)

// Fold on the file, aggregating data in a map
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[String]]) { case (acc, (key, value)) =>
    acc + (key -> (value :: acc.getOrElse(key, List.empty)))

// Now that we have the whole data as a Map, turn that into a List[Foo].
  }.map(r => Foo(r._1, r._2))
```

This never loads the input data more than once, discarding each row once it's put in the aggregation map - as opposed to your implementation which, if I'm counting right, has it 4 times in memory by the end (once as lines, once as split lines, once as a `List[Foo]` and once as an `Array[Foo]`).

Also, strings are good when you don't have a choice, but if you have better types - ints, say, or dates - use these instead. An int uses a lot less memory than its string representation.

Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This library looks promising, we will keep exploring. Awesome of you to take the time ....

Answer (score 2):

You get an automatic doubling of the size when you read a typical file into memory, since this converts single-byte character representation into two-byte JVM characters. Then thanks to a change Oracle made in a point release of Java 7, you more than double again when you split the input into substrings (prior to said change substrings referenced the backing array of the original string, but this caused a problem in the - **not** - widely-used Glassfish, so Oracle changed the behavior of the JVM to copy the substring chars to a new array; because you still have the reference to the original strings as well as the substrings you more than double memory usage).

Depending on the length of the split strings, you may be much more than doubling the memory usage - each String takes roughly 40 bytes of memory beyond the actual number of bytes in the character representation, due to the String object itself and the Array object used for the characters.

So I'd guess that this takes you about half the way to your 1.7GB usage. The rest is probably due to temporary structures created during the raw.groupBy statement, though I'd expect most of these to be released afterward.

Are you doing some delays before you check the memory usage? That would generally be needed in order to allow garbage collection to take place. After the garbage collection is done you should be able to get a reasonable estimate of actual memory usage as runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory().

Comment: For background of the Java 7 change to String, see https://www.reddit.com/comments/1qw73v Note that it was easy to avoid the sharing of the backing char[] without this change, just by using `new String(string.substring(...))`.

Comment: Thank you for that response. Manually invoking `System.gc()` reduces the overall heap to `~980MB`. I will experiment with this more.

Comment: Note that you should be able to reduce some of the extra data being held by separating out:

```val src = Source.fromFile(file)
val lines = src.getLines()
val raw = lines.map(_.split(",")).toArray
src.close()```

into a function call. That way both the lines data and the Source object should be able to be garbage collected after the call. You could also include the raw.groupBy in the call, just returning the result array.